# how to run oozie workflow for future dates

Tags: oozie

is there any way to run the oozie workflow job for future dates.
I am trying to load the data for timedimension for future date ,until december 2017.

What would be the way to run the job for 2017.

Answer (score 0):

The Oozie Coordinator system allows the user to define and execute recurrent and interdependent workflow jobs (data application pipelines). You can schedule the workflow using coordinator with a start and end date and frequency of the execution.

[Latest Oozie coordinator documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html)